# Linux shell command to grep Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B)?

Tags: linux, shell

How can I `grep` for Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B) in Linux?

```
$ grep '%U200B' filename?
```

Comment: Which distro/shell/`printf`/`grep` combination are you using?

Answer (score 11):

First, let's print one:

```
$ printf %b '\u200b' | uniname
character  byte       UTF-32   encoded as     glyph   name
        0          0  00200B   E2 80 8B               ZERO WIDTH SPACE
```

Command `uniname` is part of the [Unicode utilities](https://billposer.org/Software/unidesc.html).

Now we should be able to use the same format to search for it (using Bash):

```
$ printf %b '\u200b' | grep -q "$(printf %b '\u200b')"
$ echo $?
0
```

The trick here is that [`printf %b` treats the arguments as encoded characters](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html#tag_20_94_16), so you can use `\x` to print single-byte characters and `\u`* to print multi-byte characters.

To find it in a file, simply do this:

```
grep "$(printf %b '\u200b')" filename
```

* The POSIX specification isn't actually clear on how `%b` works. The `printf` page says "The %b conversion specification [...] has been added here as a portable way to process -escapes expanded in string operands as provided by the echo utility", and [the `echo` page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) shows a single undocumented example of its use.

Test:

```
$ printf %b '\u200b' > test.txt
$ grep -q "$(printf %b '\u200b')" test.txt
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I have to elaborate my question. I have a file in linux which has <200e> in one of the lines. NOw I need to catch it using grep in linux shell. i.e. without opening the file

Comment: grep "$(printf %b '\u200b')" filename is not working

Answer (score 4):

The following, works fine.  I created the file with BabelMap(google) and used it's save option.

Created file w/line nums 1-5 and on line 4 added the zero len space:

```
> hexdump testout.txt -C                 
00000000  31 0a 32 0a 32 0a 33 0a  34 20 e2 80 8b 0a 35 0a  |1.2.2.3.4 ....5.|
00000010
```

Note the utf8 encoding of the char 'e2808b' in the file.

This simple grep finds the correct line:

```
> grep $'\u200b' testout.txt  
4 ​
> grep $'\u200b' testout.txt|hexdump -C
00000000  34 20 e2 80 8b 0a                                 |4 ....|
00000006
```

FWIW, my GREP_OPTIONS are set: "--color=auto -I -D skip -d skip", but I don't think any of them are relevant.

Comment: `$'...'` is not portable. It was going to be my answer before I saw that OP had just tagged the question "shell".

Comment: Not just shell -- linux shell.  I don't know of any shell associate with linux as much as bash.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Perl regex with GNU grep

> grep --perl-regexp '\x{200B}' filename

In `macos` it is trickier, as the BSD grep that comes with it doesn't support multibyte. However GNU grep can be installed via Homebrew where it is made available as `ggrep`.